# How to set pagination from find results in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a code on my Ticket controller that displays all of the tickets created by the logged in user:

```
 $this->set('tickets',$this->Ticket->find('all',array('conditions'=>array('user_id'=>$this->Auth->user('id')))), $this->paginate());
```

It returns correct results, however, my pagination (when you view the index page) shows all the tickets created by all users (Page 1 of 1, showing 18 records out of 18 total, starting on record 1, ending on 18). The code above should only return 3 tickets when you view the index page.

Thanks in advance.

Lyman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
// Contoller - define pagination settings
     var $paginate = array(
                'Tickets'=>array(     
                     'limit' => 3, 
                     'order' => array( 'User.id' => 'asc' ) // or whatever
                     )
                  );
```

Now call $this->paginate instead of $this->find.

-- Editing to include conditions to find.

```
// The second argument takes your conditions. Model.field syntax is preferable.
$this->set('tickets', $this->paginate('Tickets', array("Tickets.user_id = {$this->Auth->user('id')}"));
```

See http://book.cakephp.org/view/1232/Controller-Setup and http://book.cakephp.org/view/1237/Custom-Query-Pagination

Comment: I think my question is a little bit vague but what I want really is to limit the result to the number of tickets created by the user. Say, I have 3 tickets created, when I log in it should only show the 3 tickets (Page 1 of 1, showing 3 records out of 3 total, starting on record 1, ending on 3). Your code still shows 18 records.

Comment: Your question is about pagination, not model association. Editing my answer to include corrected conditions...

Comment: Sorry but did you miss something on that line? I get a Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in \app\Controller\TicketsController.php on line 20.

Comment: Nevermind Sir, I changed it to: $this->set('tickets', $this->paginate('Ticket', array('user_id'=>$this->Auth->user('id'))));...Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm a maam not a sir sorry for the syntax error, glad to help :)